# how to convert a hash into an array with particular order? (ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash of hashes (@post) and I want to save it into csv. Strange for me is that my approach works for the header but not for the rows. If I display the rows using

`csv << (@post_csv_order.each {|element| puts single_post[element]})`

I can see the right strings on the screen but the csv files contains values of the hash key not the values of the hash values. Basically I have 5 lines of the header in my csv instead of the right values.

I think I need to convert @post[key] hash into an array with an order based on @post_csv_order (contains keys for the @post[key] hash) There is a hash method [to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002844) but it will not give me the order I need.

I guess you might suggest different approach and not to use hash of hashed but I would like to also know **how to convert hash into an array that has some pre-defined order**.

On the other hand if there is any easy way how to save **a hash of hashes into csv/table** I am happy to rewrite my code.

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'faster_csv'
  require 'pp'

  @post = {123 => {"ForumID" => "123", "Post author" => "Thom" }, 
           222 => {"ForumID" => "222", "Post author" => "Mark"},
           345 => {"ForumID" => "345", "Post author" => "Eddy"},
           444 => {"ForumID" => "444", "Post author" => "Eli"}}
  @post_csv_order = [
                      "ForumID" ,
                      "Post author"  
                     ]

  FasterCSV.open("test.csv", "w", { :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true, :return_headers => false, :force_quotes => true}) do |csv|
    csv << (@post_csv_order.each {|element| element})
       @post.each_value do |single_post|
        csv << (@post_csv_order.each {|element| single_post[element]})  
     #csv << (@post_csv_order.each {|element| puts single_post[element]})
      end 
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
csv << @post_csv_order.each {|element| single_post[element]}
```

loops over the `@post_csv_order` array and returns the array itself, which is not what you want. The `each` and the block don't actually do anything in this context. If you change `each` to `map` it will do what you want:

```
csv << @post_csv_order.map {|element| single_post[element]}
```

`map` returns a new array containing the result of each invocation of the block.

Comment: @Theo: thank you for the solution. I do not understand why `csv << (@post_csv_order.each {|element| element})` for headers work

Comment: It works because all it does is `csv << @post_csv_order`, and `@post_csv_order` contains the headers. The `.each { |element| element }` (besides being a no-op in itself) has no effect. `each` returns the array itself, the receiver of the message. `each` is just a looping construct and it's only useful if the loop has side-effects, which your loops don't. You're using `each` as if it were `map`.